# Java EE 7 - ManagedThreadFactory possible limitations

Tags: java, multithreading, java-ee-7

Java EE 7 offers some good multithreading tools with package `javax.enterprise.concurrent`. Is there any limitations when using the thread of `ManagedThreadFactory`? Can I just run this thread for infinite or will the server try to clean this up after x period of time?

I can't find much about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a look into JSR-236: https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236 and looking into it, it seems running long processes are allowed. In the document at 3.4.1.1.3 they show an example of using a `Thread` which runs in a `while` loop. Also 3.4.4.2.3 describes about priorities which **can** be used for long-running processes.

To answer my own question, according to JSR-236 it is allowed to used it for long running processes.